# Rotating image element throwing exception

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, win-universal-app

I'm trying to get the initial degree angle value of my `mainrocket_img` which is an `Image` element. To do this, I'm using a timer.. the timer is to be used to get the initial degree, and then change the value of `Angle` every second. This is my code:

```
    public void startRotationTimer()
    {
        rotationTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        rotationTimer.Tick += rotateTimer_Tick;
        rotationTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
        rotationTimer.Start();
    }

    void rotateTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        RotateTransform transform = mainrocket_img.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
        double doubleAngle = transform.Angle;
    }
```

However on line `double doubleAngle = transform.Angle;` I get this exception:

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I just can't seem to understand why? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like `transform.Angle` doesn't have a value.

Comment: do you somewhere (xaml or codebehind) initialize the rotatetransform? If not, "tranform" should be null. If you then try to access "transform.Angle" you have a problem...

Comment: @PhilipW Ah I see, so I have to initialize the property within the XAML first.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only works if you somewhere have set the `RenderTransform` property beforehand.

Set `RenderTransform` in XAML:

```
<Image>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Set `RenderTransform` in code behind:

```
void rotateTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    RotateTransform transform = mainrocket_img.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
    if (transform == null)
    {
        transform = new RotateTransform();
        mainrocket_img.RenderTransform = transform;
    }
    double doubleAngle = transform.Angle;
}
```